# Proving an if and only if statement

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Suppose I am trying to prove a statement in the form A if and only if B. I know I need to prove that

1. If A, then B
2. If B, then A

I know that 1 is equivalent to proving "If not B, then not A".

My question is: When proving A if and only if B, is it permissible to prove "if not B, then not A" and then "if B, then A."

I have seen many people prove A iff B by showing "If not A, then not B" and then "If not B, then not A," but never the way I described, which is why I am asking if it is okay.

Comment: Yes, it is fine.

Comment: That's correct, as it relies on the tautology $$\big[\mathrm{A}\iff\mathrm{B}\big]\iff\big[(\mathrm{B}\implies\mathrm{A}) \,\land(\mathrm{\lnot B}\implies\mathrm{\lnot A}) \big].$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes that is perfectly fine. A implies B is logically equivalent to "not B, then not A".

Comment: Do people avoid that structure? Or does it just not come up much? I've really never seen anyone do it before.

Comment: I've not noticed it's avoided in particular but I don't really keep track. It just might happen that it is generally less straightforward. Nothing wrong with it though. There can be more than 1 way to prove something.

Comment: @Lsonic: apart from  the fact that is going from right-to-left, this proof idiom can be very natural: in words: I want to show that $A$ and $B$ are equivalent: so let me look  at the cases for $B$: if it's false, I want to show that $A$ is false and if it's true I want to show that $A$ is true.