# Which are all the ways to proving IFF statements?

Tags: logic

Suppose I want to prove an **IFF** statement; for example:

$A \Leftrightarrow B$

I know, for instance, that I can prove such a thing by showing:

$\neg B \Rightarrow \neg A$ and $\neg A \Rightarrow \neg B$

However, is this the only way? If not, **how many logical combinations do I have to prove such a statement?**

PD: I've been searching on this website, and this is a [closely related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1676135/proving-an-if-and-only-if-statement) (although it's not exactly the same).

Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prove both $$A\implies B \tag{1}$$ and $$B\implies A\tag{2}.$$ Equivalent to $(1)$ is $$\lnot B\implies\lnot A\tag{1'}$$ and equivalent to $(2)$ is $$\lnot A\implies\lnot B\tag{2'}.$$

You need to prove something equivalent to $(1)$ and something equivalent to $(2)$. So you can prove $A\iff B$ by proving one of four combinations:

- (1) and (2)
- (1') and (2)
- (1) and (2')
- (1') and (2').

Comment: To sum up, I can prove such a thing in four different manners:

(1) $A \Rightarrow B$ and $B \Rightarrow A$; 
(2) $\neg A \Rightarrow \neg B$ and $\neg B \Rightarrow \neg A$; 
(3) $\neg A \Rightarrow \neg B$ and $B \Rightarrow A$;
(4) $A \Rightarrow B$ and $\neg B \Rightarrow \neg A$.

Am I right?

Comment: To add, sometimes you can think of a proposition $C $ and can prove $A\Leftrightarrow C $ and $C\Leftrightarrow B $.

Comment: @Héctor Actually, looking at it more closely, (3) and (4) are backwards.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you!